# How to use shared libraries?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

How can I use shared libraries without **native** method declaration and any external Java libraries?

I have to handle some raw sockets but I can't declare native methods by some reasons.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: _"I can't declare native methods by some reasons"_. That's not a particularly convincing explanation. _Why_ exactly can't you do that?

Comment: *"but I can't declare native methods by some reasons"* - Yes, you can declare them.

Comment: @Michael I'm coding at javascript level by rhino engine.

Comment: @Christian Hackl see above comment